# Getting Breadcrumbs in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, breadcrumbs, recursive-query

I have a table that represents a hierarchy by referencing itself.

```
create table nodes (
  id integer primary key,
  parent_id integer references nodes (id),
  name varchar(255)
);
```

Given a specific node, I would like to find all of its parents in order, as breadcrumbs.  For example, given this data:

```
insert into nodes (id,parent_id,name) values 
(1,null,'Root'),
(2,1,'Left'),
(3,1,'Right'),
(4,2,'LeftLeft'),
(5,2,'LeftRight'),
(6,5,'LeftRightLeft');
```

If I wanted to start at `id=5` I would expect the result to be:

```
id | depth | name
-- | ----- | ----
1  | 0     | 'Root'
2  | 1     | 'Left'
5  | 2     | 'LeftRight'
```

I don't care if the depth column is present, but I included it for clarity, to show that there should only be one result for each depth and that results should be in order of depth.  I don't care if it's ascending or descending.  The purpose of this is to be able to print out some breadcrumbs that look like this:

```
(1)Root \ (2)Left \ (5)LeftRight
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic recursive query would look like this:

```
with recursive tree(id, name, parent_id) as (
    select n.id, n.name, n.parent_id
    from nodes n
    where n.id = 5
    union all
    select n.id, n.name, n.parent_id
    from nodes n
    join tree t on (n.id = t.parent_id)
)
select *
from tree;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/713f8/1

That will give you everything need to rebuild the path from `id = 5` back to the root.

Comment: Does it not matter that you labeled both selects "n" there?  I'd think n.id would be ambiguous, unless sql is implicitly shadowing the prior definition of n.

Comment: The table alias won't cross the UNION ALL boundary between the queries; in `A UNION B`, the `A` and `B` queries have their own namespaces.